# How to blacklist some objects for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model that `has_many` `Venues` and I'd like to allow users to block venues so they won't see it in the default venue list (which shows everything).

I'm looking through documents/tutorials now before I start writing code, but I thought I'd ask here to get any advice or suggestions. Once I have the relationship working I'll post the code so anyone else working on something similar can see it.

Currently the two models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :venues, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the Venues Controller:

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @venues = Venue.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @venues }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: let me ask you a important question. Are these venues exclusive to one User? or many users could have the same venue?

Comment: Yep, I'd like to know that too, I could edit my answer with the code for a `has_many through`

Comment: They will be exclusive to one user, but I haven't set up the validations yet. I'll need to check that the name + address combo is unique since there could be multiple venues at the same address, and there will definitely be venues with the same name.

Comment: Then you should check my answer @BHOLT, it should work in your case (a Venue belongs_to User and User has_many Venues)

Comment: @MrYoshiji I think I misunderstood your exclusive question. Users will create venues that are unique so other users can't create the same venue. All users will be able to see all venues, minus they ones they've blocked. Ex. U1 create V1, V2, V3. U2 blocks V2 and only sees V1 and V3. U3 still sees all of U1's venues - V1, V2, V3.

Comment: Well in this case you need a user_blacklisted_venue model, which refer to a user_id and a venue_id ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `join_model` with the following attributes: `user_id`, `venue_id`, and `blacklisted`.

For the example, I will name it `JoinModel` but I am sure that you will find a better name.

**1. Generate the join model**

```
rails g model join_model user:references venue:references blacklisted:boolean
```

In the migration file, add a default value to the blacklisted field:

```
class CreateJoinModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :join_models do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :venue, index: true
      t.boolean :blacklisted, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Migrate: `rake db:migrate`

**2. Setup the relationships**

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_models
  has_many :users, through: :join_models
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_models
  has_many :venues, through: :join_models
end

class JoinModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

**3. Do not select the blacklisted join_models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_models, -> { where(blacklisted: false) }
  # ... 
end
```

This way, `@venues = current_user.venues` or `@users = User.includes(:venues)` won't return the blacklisted venues for this/these user(s).

**Alternative**

If you need to call `Venue.all` directly, you can set up a default scope directly on the `Venue` model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  default_scope { joins(:join_models).where(join_models: { blacklisted: false }) }
end
```

That way, `Venue.all` purge the blacklisted venues. `User.first.venues` only returns the non-blacklisted venues.

Answer (score 1):

You should create new model that provide many-to-many relationships between Venues and Users for blacklisting.
Then left only required venues

```
blacklisted_venues = User.find(params[:id]).blacklisted_venues
@venues = Venue.all.to_a - blacklisted_venues
```

Comment: `Venue.all - blacklisted_venues` would be sufficient here, eventually  with a `.to_a` after the `.all`

Comment: Thanks, now it's much better. BTW, isn't your variant exclude venue for all users?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood well your question but the alternative I proposed can be used to filter all the Venues on their flag "blacklisted" (True/False), regardless the owner (user).

Comment: I think what he's trying to say is that, with your alternatives. If one user blacklist a venue, it would be blacklisted for all of them, even if they don't want it blacklisted.